# Python turtle, using colours from a list

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
colours =  [turtle.color("red"),turtle.color("blue"),turtle.color("yellow"),turtle.color("green")]

fred = colours[0],turtle.forward(100),turtle.left(90),colours[1],turtle.forward(100),turtle.left(90),colours[2],turtle.forward(100),turtle.left(90),colours[3],turtle.forward(100),turtle.left(90)
```

Attemping to make a square with 4 different colours from a list, type(colours[0]) returns class Nonetype. How can I access the colours from my list?

Comment: I would seem that `turtle.color("red")` returns `None`?

Comment: It does, type(turtle.color("red")) returns None, but if you enter turtle.color("red") it will change the colour. I thought that using colours[0] should have the same effect, but it accepts the command with no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

`colours =  [turtle.color("red")]`

Will run the function `turtle.color("red")`, and store the return value in the list.

This is *exactly* the same as doing:

`colours =  [None]`

If you call `colours[0]` you get the return value, not the function. Python has no idea if the `None` ended up there through a function call, or if you just assigned it manually.

You only posted 2 lines of code, so I don't quite know what the context is here, but you *may* want to do something like:

```
colours =  [lambda: turtle.color("red"), lambda: turtle.color("blue")]
```

What this does, is store a lamba (or 'anonymous function') in your list. This function is *not executed*. You will now get:

```
>>> colours[0]
<function <lambda> at 0x80089e710>
```

And you can execute this as many times as you want by appending parenthesis, like so: `colours[0]()`

This technique is known as 'currying' by the way.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a nice clear explanation and works perfectly.